# External javascript files not loading properly in Firefox, or sometimes not at all

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm having a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out by looking at the developer tools. All of my javascript files seem to be loading when I look at the 'network' tab in Firefox, but every time I refresh it seems (quite randomly) one or two of my javascript files will not be functioning properly.

I am super confused as to what could be causing this. I am loading all my `<script>` tags at the bottom of my html document before the closing `</body>` tag. Is there somewhere else I should be loading them for firefox? When I test this on my dev server everything loads fine, but when I upload it to AppEngine some of my js files just choose not to load.

Is there some weird thing with timeouts or loading order for firefox that I should be aware of? Or some random setting that I have turned off somewhere? I can't seem to find any documentation on the matter, either, so any links to reading would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces this behavior?

Comment: *"Is there somewhere else I should be loading them for firefox?"* No. Beyond that, we can't help you without significantly more information.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, this isn't Firefox specific issue, FF just happens to be the browser that you are encounter it in. This is a common issue when loading js assets at runtime.

***tl:dr***

If you are loading assets from different locations that can cause runtime inconsistencies, shoot, even if you are requesting two separate assets from the **same** location you can run into issues since they are occurring in separate requests and are subject to network performance.

*Option One:*

Consolidate the js assets that are being render inconsistantly.
So if you're loading the following:

- jquery.js
- script-one.js
- script-two.js

Then concat them into one asset:

- jquery.js
- scripts.js

*Option Two:*

Use a module system like [require](http://requirejs.org/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

***Longer Answer***

If you are loading assets into the browser at runtime that require each other to be loaded in order to function there will always be a certain degree of risk if you aren't using any sort of module loader or build process to mitigate the solution.

*Say you have to following situation*

You have jquery and three plugins which needs to be loaded in a particular order. Just because you have your tags stacked in a particular order doesn't guarantee that is the order they will be available at runtime. Take the following:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>
<script src="widget.js"></script>
```

Its very possible that these could load jquery > widget > modal, then jquery > modal > widget on the next. It might seem like someone is messing you, but that's just the world wide webs doing its thing. As I stated above there are common ways to solve this problem that are already well vetted and I suggest looking into them. This is also one of the main features on ES6 that people are VERY excited to for.

Hope that clears up your FF gremlins! Cheers.

Comment: I'll try consolidating my js files, I have like 7 right now (old website, eek). Thank you for the links, browserify looks promising